# The Insert function does not work for the head node in my Linked List in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I wrote this function to insert nodes into a linked list:

```
node *insert(node *head){
    node *newn;
    node *n1;
    int x;
    int key;
    printf("\nEnter the number you would like to insert: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("\nEnter the key element you want to insert the element before(-999 for last): ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    
    if(head -> number == key)
    {
        newn = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        newn -> number = x;
        newn -> next = head;
        head = newn;
    }
    else
    {
        n1 = find(head, key);
        if (n1 == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nKey not found...");
    
        }
        else
        {
            newn = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
            newn -> number = x;
            newn -> next = n1 -> next;
            n1 -> next = newn;
        }
    }
    return(head);
    
}
```

This works for inserting nodes at the end or at in between nodes but when I try to insert the node in the beginning it just never prints it

Here is the entire code with the printLL function that prints the list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct linkedList
{
    int number;
    struct linkedList *next;
};

typedef struct linkedList node;

void create(node *list);
void printLL(node *list);
int count(node *list);
node *insert(node *head);
node *find (node *list, int key);

int main() {
    node *head;
    head = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    create(head);
    puts("\n\n");
    printLL(head);
    puts("\n\n");
    printf("The number of elements are %d", count(head));
    puts("\n\n");
    insert(head);
    printLL(head);
    return 0;
    
}

void create(node *list){
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number you want to add(-999) to end: ");
    scanf("%d", &list->number);
    
        
    if(list -> number == -999)
    {
        list -> next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        list -> next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        create(list-> next);
    }
    return;
}

void printLL(node *list){
    if(list -> next != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d -->", list -> number);
        
        if(list -> next -> next == NULL)
        {
            printf(" END");
        }
        
        printLL(list -> next);
    }
    return;
}

int count(node *list){
    if(list -> next == NULL) return 0;
    else return(1 + count(list->next));
}


node *insert(node *head){
    node *newn;
    node *n1;
    int x;
    int key;
    printf("\nEnter the number you would like to insert: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("\nEnter the key element you want to insert the element before(-999 for last): ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    
    if(head -> number == key)
    {
        newn = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        newn -> number = x;
        newn -> next = head;
        head = newn;
    }
    else
    {
        n1 = find(head, key);
        if (n1 == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nKey not found...");
    
        }
        else
        {
            newn = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
            newn -> number = x;
            newn -> next = n1 -> next;
            n1 -> next = newn;
        }
    }
    return(head);
    
}

node *find (node *list, int key){
    
    if(list -> next -> number = key)
    {
        return(list);
    }
    else 
    {
        if (list -> next == NULL)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            find(list -> next, key);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: In order to insert in the head, you need to be able to modify the `head` value. But you pass it by value into the function and `head = newn;` has no effect outside the function.

Comment: `insert(head);` ==> `head = insert(head);`